# OziExplorer maps not rendered correctly in QGIS

Tags: qgis

When I open up some OziExplorer (.ozf2) maps in QGIS they are not rendered correctly in that they appear reversed or in-versed. Text on the map is not legible and looks to be in-versed but this is not the case (looking via a mirror confirms this). Find this very strange and looking for some help.

Maps from http://maps.festy.org/